# how do I represent negative decimal verilog

Tags: math, verilog, fixed-point

I have converted some decimal values into fixed point and want to carry out some multiplication, however some of these values are negative can anyone show me an easy way to carry out the multiplication I have tried this but had no success:

`pix_r2m<=($signed({1'b0,pix_rld})*8'b11101101;// the binary is:-0.148.`

This is happening in a synchronous manner and `pix_r2m`, `pix_rld` are defined as :

```
reg [16:0]pix_r2m;
reg [7:0]pix_rld;
```

Comment: @ morgan could you look at my verilog as a whole there is a lot more code

Comment: If the code is in a compiling state then it can be posted on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise here on SO is best place to tackle each issue separately.

Comment: @Morgan how would I am representing -0.148 as 8 bits and in decimal that should give me -38 how do I represent it as a decimal rather than binary?

Comment: You have not actually stated what format your data is. assuming 8 bits of fractional. 0.148 * 2^8 is 38 (8 fractional bits). that is 8 decimal to convert to binary in ruby (irb) on the command line I can do `38.to_s(2)` => "100110" That is the positive version if want negative perform twos complement on it.

Comment: Verilog does not care about decimal or binary or hex, as they all just represent binary bit patterns. I was asking so that I could check the decimal/binary point was where you though you were placing it. but in this instance I think the issue was verilog reverting back to unsigned arithmetic. but you have not provided an input stimulus and expected output and the wrong output you actually see, therefore it is hard to tell if I have fixed the correct issue.

Comment: @ morgan managed to sort it thanks for the advice proved to be very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog given any opportunity will revert to unsigned arithmetic, here the multiplicand or coefficient is unsigned. Telling it is signed with 8'**s**b, allows correct sign extension to take place.

```
module test;
  reg [16:0]pix_r2m;
  reg [7:0]pix_rld;

  always @* begin
    //* -0.148
    pix_r2m = $signed({1'b0,pix_rld}) * 8'sb11110111;
  end

  initial begin
    pix_rld = {4'd1,4'd0}; //1
    #1 $display("%b", pix_r2m);


    pix_rld = {4'd2,4'd0}; //2
    #1 $display("%b", pix_r2m);
  end


endmodule
```

[EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2DcS).

But you likely want the result to be flagged as signed so you should be using :

```
reg signed [16:0]pix_r2m;
```